# Are curve secp256k1 ECDSA signatures distinguishable from random data?

Tags: dsa, secp256k1

Are the 64-byte curve secp256k1 ECDSA signatures distinguishable from random data?

I.e. Given a random private key and random data, will there be patterns?

Is there a proof or reasoning for this?

Comment: Note that DER encoded signatures consist of a SEQUENCE (byte value `30`) with two INTEGER (byte value `02` encoded values) for ECDSA. So if the signature is of X9.62 form then it will be recognizable and **obviously** not random data. However, the "flat" representation - just $r$ and $s$ concatenated - then it is up to the values of $r$ is $s$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We know that the standard encoding of points of an elliptic curve is not uniformly random since they must satisfy the curve equation. In another look, we don't have $2*p^2$ points, and if we consider the curve and it's quadratic twist ($p>3$) then their total number of points is $2p+2$ which is way lower than possible.

In ECDSA, the $r$ is calculated as $r = x_1 \bmod n$ where $x_1 = x([k]G)$. Therefore the $r$ is not uniform random. Since we have $n \approx p$<sup>‡</sup> ( by Hasse's theorem $|n - (p+1)| \le 2 \sqrt{p}$), then we can consider that $r = x_1$ and use the curve equation to see that $r$ satisfies the curve equation or not. If satisfied then it is distinguished.

The $s$ on the other hand is uniform random if the private key $d_A$ and random $k$ are selected uniformly randomly.

**Bonus** :

- For the prime curves, like secp256k, one should use [Elligator Squared](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/043.pdf) as pointed out our [Mehdi Tibouchi](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108743/are-curve-secp256k-ecdsa-signatures-distinguishable-from-random-data/108744?noredirect=1#comment232998_108744) as the writer of the paper.
- For the curves with non-trivial 2-torsion, like Curve25519, Curve448
  you can use [Elligator](https://elligator.cr.yp.to/elligator-20130828.pdf) This is the core of the paper. See on more on [elligator.org](https://elligator.org/)

With this work, the suitable curves, and the points are indistinguishable from uniform random strings and make $r$ as uniform random.

---

<sub><sup>‡</sup> For Secp256k1 $p-n = 432420386565659656852420866390673177326$, currently tested 1000000 random points on the curve and in all $r =x_1$. Looking for existence.</sub>

1 . One example is found with random range in (n,p-1)$$\small{(115792089237316195423570985008687907853210556320040394375440737845891899649421 : 7121023256299234636881590140965649586172043956329380565516515841646015336371 )}$$

Comment: I'll hash the signature to fix any issues.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a hash is a usual solution to remove any structure of the inputs like we did in ECDE or signatures.

Comment: Elligator won't work on a prime order curve like secp256k1, but you can use Elligator Squared.

Comment: @MehdiTibouchi you are right. Updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: "though finding a distinguisher requires a deep analysis"; not that deep - we have $r = x_1$ almost all the time (because $n \approx p$ the characteristic of the curve), and we can easily check if a potential $x_1$ is a possible x-coordinate to the curve equation...

Comment: @poncho that is true, indeed is enough to distinguish most of the time. I was considering it quantitatively hard. Added.

Comment: @fgrieu $16 \neq  - 27 + 7$. However, interestingly there is a point with $x=p-3$ and $y =6603225675942137755722016048183769717410321709583529039474051610042430502525$ of course this is because $-7$ is QR. $p-3,p-4, p-10,p-12$ are other candidates.

Comment: @kelalaka: you beat me at fixing it: it's easy to generate a point on secp256k1 with $n\le x<p$ thus $r=x-n\ne x$. One example is $(x,y)=(p−3,y)$ with the above $y$ that you found. However it is hard find a $k$ matching such $r$ and AFAIK it was never done. Without it, I don't see how to generate a valid signature with such $r$, even when choosing message and public key.

Answer (score 7):

Reformulating slightly<sup>1</sup>:

> Can we distinguish from 64-byte of random data an [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) signature (without ASN.1 formatting) for curve secp256k1, unknown random key pair and message?

**Yes**, with excellent advantage.

For a valid signature with private key $d$, the first 32 bytes code (per big-endian convention) an integer $r=x\bmod n$ where $x$ is the X coordinate of a point $k\,G$ on the curve $y^2\equiv x^3+b\pmod p$, and the next 32 bytes code an integer $s=k^{−1}(e+r\,d)\bmod n$ where $e$ is a 256-bit hash of the message and $k$ is random in $[1,n)$ except it's not such that $s=0$. It follows that (where $p$, $n$ and $b=7$ are given for [secp256k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.4.1)):

1. It holds $0<r<n$
2. It holds $0<s<n$
3. There exists an integer $y$ with $y^2\equiv r^3+b\pmod p$. Given that $p$ is prime and $-b$ is not a cube modulo $p$, this is equivalent to $\displaystyle\left(\frac{r^3+b}p\right)=+1$ (see [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol)), equivalently to $(r^3+b)^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$, which is easily checked.

With probability just above $1/2$, a random 64-byte string parsed as $r$ and $s$ fails one of these three tests<sup>2</sup>, in which case we are sure it's not an ECDSA signature for curve secp256k1. If it passes these three tests, then there exists a message and a public/private key pair making the signature valid. More precisely: for almost every message there exist exactly 2 key pairs (it can also be 0 or 4 in some edge cases). It's possible to find these key pairs, using [ECDSA public key recovery](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.4.1.6).

Any valid ECDSA signature for secp256k1 pass these three tests. Hence the above distinguisher has [advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advantage_(cryptography)) $>1/2$.

---

<sup>1</sup> In particular, replacing *given* with *unknown*: if the message and private key are given we can check the signature, and that's a hell of a distinguisher. And since an [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) format allows a trivial distinguisher, we must suppose it is used the (usually more compact, and also common) format defined in IEEE Std 1363-2000 E.3.1, that I quote with adaptation of the notation:

> (…) the output of the signature generation function is a pair of integers $(r,s)$. Let $n$ denote the order of the generator ($g$ or $G$) in the DL or EC settings, and let $\ell=\bigl\lceil\log_{256}n\bigr\rceil$ (i.e., $\ell$ is the length of $n$ in octets). The output $(r,s)$ may be formatted as an octet string as follows: convert the integers $r$ and $s$ to octet strings $R$ and $S$, respectively, of length $\ell$ octets each, using the primitive I2OSP, and output the concatenation $R\mathbin\|S$. To parse the signature, split the octet string into two components $R$ and $S$, of length $\ell$ each, and convert them to integers $r$ and $s$, respectively, using OS2IP. Note that it is essential that both $R$ and $S$ be of length $\ell$, even if it means that they have leading zero octets.

<sup>2</sup> Mostly, test 3: because $n$ of secp256k1 is just below $2^{256}$ (within $1.3\times2^{128}$), there is probability $<2^{-126}$ that condition 1 or 2 is exploitable to reject a 64-byte random value as a signature. As noted in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/233011), that's curve-specific, and for some curves test 1 and 2 are very selective. Also, for some curves, test 3 would need adaptation.

Comment: Just a small note that e.g. Brainpool curves may have an $n$ that's not so close to the nearest power of two - or rather power of 256 if we assume bytes. And for the prime curves there is of course secp512r1 which definitely isn't on a byte boundary. It won't help you distinguish anything about the private key, but detecting a (sufficiently large) set of signatures would be easy.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes. And there is also [secp224k1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsection.2.3) which ECDSA signatures sans ASN.1 should be 58 bytes including one always and another almost always 0x00, except if we invent a convention to try another $k$ should it happen otherwise. I wonder if that's done IRL, and how many makeshift parsers / signature / verification gear get the edge cases wrong.